# removing ubuntu from a dual boot system (xp/ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, multi-boot

i have a dual boot system with xp and Ubuntu. Now i wish to remove Ubuntu from the system.
I checked run->compmgmt.msc->Disk Management. There it shows the primary partitions and I am able to identify the one containing Ubuntu (with option to delete that partition)My doubts are:

1. Can i directly delete the partition containing ubuntu (without needing the CD)
2. can I use a tool like partition magic (without losing the data on XP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete Ubuntu partitions, you will have to reinstall Windows bootloader to your hard disc's MBR (MBR is first 512 bytes of your booting hard drive), where currently there is a GRUB bootloader used by Ubuntu. You can reinstall Windows bootloader by running Windows Repair from Windows installation disc. I suggest you do that before deleting any Ubuntu partitions and see whether it works - if it does, you should not be able to enter Ubuntu. Only then it is safe to delete Ubuntu partitions.
This is the only possible solution involving deletion of Ubuntu partitions. Otherwise GRUB in MBR will be looking for its configuration files in /boot folder on Ubuntu partitions, which do not exist.

Comment: what about partition magic? Is there a way out without using the CD?

Comment: Not really. You will have to reinstall MBR anyways, because GRUB, which is currently in MBR, will require Ubuntu partition for a successful boot. But you can try reinstalling MBR from Windows XP without CD: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/110679#110679